# Unable to create Socket after creating 1020 times to communicate

Tags: c, linux, sockets, gcc

I am following the socket programming tutorial from this link [Socket programming](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/). and trying to develop an application where client will receive Network Time from Server and print the time .  Here is how the program works-

Server is waiting for incoming connection and while client try to connect with server , server accept the connection and server sends the time to client. After receiving through socket client print the time.

After every message send to client , server close the connection and wait for next. **Client is able to communicate with server** **for 1020 times**. **If I try to communicate  more than 1020 time from client to server then I got**  **Error- Unable to Create Socket**

I am trying to develop the application where client can communicate with server **infinite times** or **atleast 20000 times.**

**I am suspecting , may be memory is not freed while creating socket in client side.**

```
Sample output :

counter=1017 Sun Jul  6 03:19:48 2014
counter=1018 Sun Jul  6 03:19:48 2014
counter=1019 Sun Jul  6 03:19:48 2014
counter=1020 Sun Jul  6 03:19:48 2014
```

***Error : Could not create socket*** (WHY ??)

Here is my code

## Server.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    char sendBuff[1025];
    time_t ticks; 

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    listen(listenfd, 10); 

    while(1)
    {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 

        ticks = time(NULL);
        snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
        write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff)); 

        close(connfd);
      //  sleep(1);
     }
}
```

> ### Client.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
    char recvBuff[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("\n Usage: %s <ip of server> \n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    } 

int counter=0;

while(counter <2000)
{
    memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    } 

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
    {
        printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
        return 1;
    } 

    if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
       printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
       return 1;
    } 

    while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
    {
        recvBuff[n] = 0;
        printf("counter=%d ",counter);
        fputs(recvBuff, stdout);
       /*
        if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF)
        {
            printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
        }
        */ 
    } 
    
counter++;
}
    if(n < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Read error \n");
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc under Ubuntu. Any help to understand the reason and resolve and run the program for around 20000 will be highly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at `setsockopt()` and SO_REUSEADDR too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not closing your client's socket after using it. You need this line in your client code:

```
close(sockfd);
```

After your while loop.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be leaking a socket in your client code.  You're creating sockets inside your outer loop, but you never close them.  Try adding `close(sockfd);` to the end of your outer loop, and to all points where you break or return out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the same client for connecting to the server , you dont need to start all over again the socket & connect process , You Can block the client till you get some data from server.  Otherwise , you are unnecessary wasting lot of kernel resources and you are closing and opening at a very rapid phase too , which is not a good idea !

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. 
In my situation, after `fopen("/proc/net/route" , "r");`, I forgot to `fclose()`.

After `fopen("/proc/net/route" , "r");`, I found the socket number increased, so I think this is the same problem.